# Can SSDT 2019 packages deployed on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2019, ssdt-2017, ssdt-2019

Can SSDT 2019 packages deployed on SQL Server 2014?

I don't have to install SQL Server 2019 for SSDT 2019 and should be able to deploy package to 2014, correct?

Comment: You can't deploy 2019 packages to 2014 no. You would need to change the TargetServerVersion property on the project to SQL Server 2014, which would change the packages to 2014. This will mean that if you have any script tasks they could become invalid, due to an older version of .Net being used.

Comment: I mean i can deploy it to SQL 2014 but you're correct about target version, script task, potential driver issues as well. Thanks